# Probability of passing a true-false test if a student knows some of the answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

> A true-false test consits of 8 questions. A student will sit for the
>   test, but will only be able to guess at each of the answers. [...] The
>   following week, the same student will sit for another true-false test,
>   this time there will be 12 questions on the test, of which he knows
>   the answer to 4. What are the chances of passing this test (assuming that 50% is a pass)?

So my approach is that if he knows the answer to 4, then he only has to guess the answer to 2 or more of the remaining questions (that he has to guess answer to), because only then his score will be equal to or over 50%. So I would do:

If $X$ is the number of the remaining questions he answers correctly:
$$P(X\ge2)= {8 \choose 2}0.5^20.5^6 + {8 \choose 3}0.5^30.5^7 + ...+{8 \choose 8}0.5^80.5^0$$

$$P(X\ge2)\approx0.9648$$

Is this correct? If no, what is the solution?

Comment: What on earth does the first part of the question (the $8$-question test) has to do with all the rest???

Comment: This task consisted of (a), (b), (c) and (d). The first sentence is an introduction to the first three, I included it in case someone will search for this question in the future.

Comment: BTW, the answer is simply $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{8} \binom{8}{n} \cdot \left(\frac12\right)^{n} \cdot \left(1-\frac12\right)^{8-n}$.

Comment: I think that when posting a question you should include **only** the relevant pieces of information.

Comment: So that's the same what I have written?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have essentially split-ed (past-tense for "split") the scenario into **disjoint** events, and then added up their probabilities. I think that using the formula that I have specified in one of the comments above might emphasize this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps easier to compute the fail case.  Will fail if answers (out of the remaining 8) 0 or 1 questions.

$
P(\text{Fail}) = {8 \choose 0} (\frac12)^8 +  {8 \choose 1}(\frac12)^8  = \frac{1+8}{256}
$